# LED Monitor brightness

Tags: display, lcd, led, backlight

I am in the market for a new monitor. I've been looking around and it seems that the general brightness for monitors is between 250-320 cd/m2.

After hours of searching, I narrowed it down to the [LG W2453V-PF](http://www.lg.com/us/computer-products/monitors/LG-lcd-monitor-W2453V-PF.jsp) vs. the [LG E2350V-SN](http://www.lg.com/us/computer-products/monitors/LG-lcd-monitor-E2350V-SN.jsp)

The W2453V-PF is not LED backlit yet it has a brightness level of 310 cd/m2 and a response time of 2ms. The E2350V-SN, on the other hand, has a brightness level of 250 cd/m2 and a response time of 5ms but it *is* LED backlit.

My questions are, looking at these overall specs:

Which monitor is better?
What makes LED backlight better?
Is the LED backlight worth the decreased brightness level?

Thanks!

p.s. if you have any other comparable monitor suggestions (that are not samsung - I read their customer service is absolutely terrible), feel free to share. thanks!

---

Update: ended up going with the LG W2453V and it's by far one of the best purchases I've ever made. The warm up time is very barely noticable, it doesn't have an annoying flickering  light (or any light for that matter) when turned off (so I can sleep with ease in the same room) and it's just all in all a great monitor. Also, I got it for $80 less than the Amazon listed price by buying directly from the Amazon warehouse (the external cardboard box was damaged - the monitor was in perfect, new condition). I'm very happy! thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LED backlight may or may not be more power efficient (check the monitors' power usage). If it is the RGB (as opposed to white) type it can produce a wider color gamut. It also produces less environmental pollution (mercury) on disposal.

See [LED Backlights](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backlight#LED_backlights) and [Differences between LED-backlit and CCFL-backlit LCD displays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LED-backlit_LCD_television#Differences_between_LED-backlit_and_CCFL-backlit_LCD_displays)

Comment: Thanks. In your opinion, which monitor is better?

Comment: It's a personal choice but I think I might go for the W2453V-PF. It has a TV tuner :) (and other features the E2350V-SN lacks)

Comment: that's the one I went with, and I'm VERY happy!